# Why does Idris conflate a value name with a type argument name that is subsequently defined?

Tags: idris

Haskell allows:

```
a:: Int 
a = 3
data MyList a = Nil | Cons a (MyList a)
```

Whereas Idris will complain with `a is bound as an implicit`, 
and I need to use a different type argument:

```
a: Int 
a = 3
data MyList b = Nil | Cons b (MyList b)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, Idris does not conflate them here, because `a` is lower case. But it *could* – other than Haskell – because it supports values in types. So the compiler warns you, because that is a common source for errors. Suppose you write:

```
n : Nat
n = 3

doNothing : Vect n Int -> Vect n Int
doNothing xs = xs
```

You might expect that `doNothing`'s type is `Vect 3 Int -> Vect 3 Int`. But instead [lower case arguments are bound to be implicit](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#implicit-arguments) and `doNothing`'s type is actually `{n : Nat} -> Vect n Int -> Vect n Int`, despite the previous declared `n`. You'd have to write `Vect Main.n Int` or make `N` upper case to use it.

So the compiler thinks that maybe you wanted to do something similiar with the `a` in `MyList a` and warns you.